# How to map errorType using Micronaut client annotation

Tags: java, annotations, micronaut, micronaut-client

How to map errorType using Micronaut client annotation, In case of programatically we can provide body type and errorType objects in case of success and failure.

Programmatically calling client:

```
import io.micronaut.core.type.Argument;
import io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest;
import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse;
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType;
import io.micronaut.http.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientResponseException;
import io.micronaut.http.uri.UriBuilder;
import io.reactivex.Single;
import java.net.URL;

@Singleton
public class Test{
    public User getUser(String id) {
        try {
            String uriPath = UriBuilder.of("url")
                            .queryParam("id", id)
                            .toString();

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new URL(""),httpClientConfiguration);

        Single<HttpResponse<User>> single = Single.fromPublisher(httpClient.exchange(
        HttpRequest.GET(uriPath).header(X_REQUEST_ID, REQUEST_ID).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE),
        Argument.of(User.class), //bodyType
        Argument.of(Object.class) //errorType
        ));

        HttpResponse<User> response = single.blockingGet();
        User user = response.body();
        return user;            
        } catch (HttpClientResponseException | Exception e ) {              
        } 
    }
}
```

Calling Client using annotations

```
import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse;
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Consumes;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Header;
import io.micronaut.http.client.annotation.Client;
import io.reactivex.Single;
@Client(value = "url",
path = "/user")
public interface TestClient {
    @Get("?id=123")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        Single<HttpResponse<User>> getUser();
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to define your own custom object as errorType, you can declare when using declarative client in micronaut as follows:

```
@Client(id="",//The ID of the client
            value = "url", //The URL or service ID of the remote service
            path = "/user",//The base URI for the client. Only to be used in conjunction with id().
            errorType=YourCustomObject.class,//The type used to decode errors
            configuration=<? extends HttpClientConfiguration>//The http client configuration bean to use
            )
public interface ExternalCallClient{
    //some API method
}
```

Then at your connector client class:

```
class Connect{

@Inject
private ExternalCallClient externalCallClient;

call(){

    try{
        //call to external API method using externalCallClient
      }catch(HttpClientResponseException e){

         Optional<YourCustomObject> error = e.getResponse()
                                             .getBody(YourCustomObject.class)
            }
        }
    }
```

Micronaut client throw a HttpClientResponseException for HTTP code(400 and above 400(except 404)) in case of exception from underlying client.
So if the underlying client provides a custom error object in case of exception as a response body, this custom error type can be used for gracefully error handling and logging.

Similar approach can be used for DefaultHttpClient too.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Micronaut API doc, errorType available with @Client annotation, it worked for me to handle the errorType response.

https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/index.html
https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#clientAnnotation

```
@Client(id="",//The ID of the client
        value = "url", //The URL or service ID of the remote service
        path = "/user",//The base URI for the client. Only to be used in conjunction with id().
        errorType=Object.class,//The type used to decode errors
        configuration=<? extends HttpClientConfiguration>//The http client configuration bean to use
        )
@Header(name="", value="")      
public interface TestClient {
    @Get("?id=123")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Single<HttpResponse<User>> getUser();
   }
```